# Java .dat operations Excercise

Tags: java

Today is my first day at Java, i'm really new at this, have been solving some problems, but I'm stucked. I know it's really simple but I hope you can help me. Thanks!

I want to identify if an Apple is a Green or Red. 
These are the requirements:

- All Apples will be listed in the following file:  apples.dat
- We must divide the results in Red or Green
- Villains are those Super-Powered people whose names contain a "A".
- Green Apples must be saved in a file called green.dat
- Red Apples must be saved in a file called red.dat

So my 2 main concerns, is how to operate with .dat files, and secondly, how to treat the fact that the condition to identify one or another may vary in a future.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is gotta be a pattern to differentiate between super heros and villains in the file? Apart from D. How does your file containing the data look? Can you update your question to include a bit of details on input data as well?

Comment: Which one of those are Villains and which ones are superhero? And why?

Comment: See the answer, it prints the superheros and villains, I will update the answer to show how to save them back to files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open a file in java, it is easy. You need to do the following:

- Create File object referencing the file
- Create BufferedReader and pass it FileReader object to which pass File object
- Use the BufferedReader's readLine() method to read line by line in while loop with condition while (line != null)
- Process the line that has been read.
- Wrap above in try/catch block

See below sample code, that read apples.dat file and print out all those who are reds and greens as well as output greens and reds in greens.dat and reds.dat repectively.

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReadFileJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //list that stores all greens 
        ArrayList<String> greens = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        //list that stores all reds
        ArrayList<String> reds = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        //file that references the file containing all green and red apples
        File file = new File("C:\\test_java\\apples.dat");

        //try and catch block in case file not found or any other I/O error
        try {

            //open the file
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            //keep reading line by line, if end of file then line == null
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                //if line contains "d" then Green it is and add it
                //to the list of reds
                if(line.indexOf("d") != -1) {
                    System.out.println("Green found!");
                    greens.add(line); 
                } else {
                    //add it to the list of superheors.
                    System.out.println("Red found.");
                    reds.add(line); 
                }
            }

            //close the reading file resource 
            br.close();

            //file to print greens back 
            File greensFile = new File("C:\\test_java\\greens.dat"); 

            //file to print reds
            File redsFile = new File("C:\\test_java\\reds.dat"); 

            //PrintStream takes care of open stream to files above
            //and writing line by line, first write greens 
            PrintStream output = new PrintStream(redsFile);

            //loop through list of previously created greens
            for(int i = 0; i < greens.size(); i++) {
                //write hered to file
                output.println(reds.get(i));
            }

            //redirect the print stream to greens file 
            output = new PrintStream(greensFile);

            //loop through list of greens
            for(int i = 0; i < greens.size(); i++) {
               //add green to the file 
                output.println(greens.get(i));
            }

            //close the output stream
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //if file not found, or any other I/O error, then error
            //so check the location of file
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Separated file for greens.dat and reds.dat are created in the locations specified (please change the location from `C:\\test_java\\filename.extension` to wherever your files are located).

Comment: There you go. I fully commented the lines of code and provided explanations on how to achieve this. Hopefully reading the answer, you will understand how everything works. Please don't forget to mark the question as **accepted** if you understood and all worked.

Comment: First you need to figure out what differentiates the two if not "d" then code that differentiation factor. I see a bunch of lines and if you ask me what are they, I would say probably name of people.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Java.
Java covers a LOT of topics so, it doesn't hurt (much) to ask for some advice on getting started.

Some basic things you will need to know before getting started:

basic things #1) Editing files: you'll need to be able to edit files.

Some files will hold your Java programs.
Other files will hold your data (like a list of names).

basic things #2) Running a Java program: Verify you understand how to make HelloWorld run.

search google for: java hello world step by step

basic things #3) If-statements:

search google for: java introduction to if statemetns

basic #4) Strings: you'll need to know how to define and work with Strings.

search google for: java introduction to strings

Now we can start by breaking down what you need to do.

step 1) Figure out how to work with names.

Hint: you'll want use java's String type to hold names.

step 2) Find out if a name includes the letter "D".

Hint: search google for: java how to find out if a character is in a string

step 3) Read names from a file.

Hint: search google for: java how to read a string from a file line by line

step 4) Write a name to a file (specific file depends on #1).

Hint: search google for: java how to write to a file line by line

hint: you will want to open two files for output, one for Heroes and and one for Villains.

hint: don't use the same file name to read from and write to; make up different file names for writing to.

Good luck to you, being at the very bottom of a learning curve can be an uncomfortable place to be.

Keep working at it.

closing hint: Google is your friend (I hope the above examples are a little bit helpful, sometimes when you're just starting out it can be hard to know what to search for).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This will help me for sure!